# C program rounds down input values

Tags: c

I need help,

I have this code to validate the input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int checkInput1(void);

int main(){

    float a = checkInput1();

    printf("The value of a is:%f\n" , a);
} 

  int checkInput1(void){
    float option1,check1;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Enter the first side of the triangle");

        if(scanf("%f%c",&option1,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            while((check1 = getchar()) != 0 && check1 != '\n' && check1 != EOF);
            printf("\t[ERR] Invalid number for the triplet.\n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    printf("returning the value of option1, which is %f\n", option1);
    return option1;



}
```

my problem is that if I input for example 78.8

The output would be:

```
Enter the first side of the triangle78.8                                                                 
returning the value of option1, which is 78.800003                                                       
The value of a is:78.000000
```

I would like it to say the following:

```
Enter the first side of the triangle78.8                                                                 
returning the value of option1, which is 78.800003                                                       
The value of a is:78.800000
```

what have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `int checkInput1(void){` ---> `float checkInput1(void){`

Comment: It's because your `checkInput1()` function is returning an `int`

Comment: Try to use `double` instead of `float`. Double has a better precision. The floating point values are rounded in a particular way. This way grants to represents big numbers, but it doesn't grant the total precision.

Comment: As @JohnnyMopp says the function should return float, or, if you follow my suggestion, it should be return a double.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini there is more to changing to `double` than that.

Comment: `if(scanf("%f%c",&option1,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){` is a problem should `scanf("%f%c",&option1,&c)` return `EOF`.  The value of `c` may not be known/initialized here so `c != '\n'` can lead to UB.

Comment: `float check1;` is a curious chice .  I'd expect `int check1;`.  @Gehteuch Nixan: did you write this code originally?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `int` from the function, which is the integral type that does not hold fractional type. Look at your declaration: `int checkInput1(void)`. `int` before function name (`checkInput1`) signifies the type returned. Consider using other type there.